# Does Angular use browser's History API for the routing?

Tags: angular, browser-history

I want to create a simple single page JS application. I wanted to use Angular for the Routes, since I think it has good browser compatibility, but it has huge bundle size for just using the routing functionality.

Does Angular use browser's History API for the routing?

If it does, I won't be so worried about browser's compatibility and I'll just write my own plugin with History API (I'll also use jQuery on my app).
Thanks!

Comment: Take care of the compatibility between Angular and JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Most client side libraries such as React, Vue or Angular etc. make use of the History API.